# Calendar api in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm making app where users can add reminders and update them
so I want to know how to add,update and delete reminders through calendar api in swift?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/SimpleEKDemo/SimpleEKDemo.zip 
This is the sample project provided by apple.
Download it and investigate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a Calendar / Reminder API called EventKit:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

This should allow you to achieve what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the help but its in objective c language I couldn't find the documentation for swift